# Increased Speed while using NSTimer

Tags: iphone, animation, nstimer

I have created an animated game app, In which I am using NSTimer to move an image after a particular interval of time.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTImerInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(MoveVirus) userinfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

this timer calls up the function MoveVirus, MoverVirus moves virus (an Image on screen).

It works fine in the beginning but the speed of motion automatically increases.
The increased speed of motion destroys every further logic.

I don't know what is the problem with it?

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please post the code of `-MoveVirus`

Comment: What does `-MoveVirus` (btw, in. Obj-C your method names should begin with lowercase characters) do?

Comment: NSLog anything in the MoreVirus method and look at the timestamps in your console.  Do they remain roughly 0.2 secs apart?  If the timer is indeed speeding up, then you have a very interesting problem here.  But I think you'll find it's running on time, and something in the animation is tricking your eye.

Comment: You are probably firing your timer multiple times but cant tell without more code

Comment: Yup actually I was firing timer for multiple times... sorry I could not reply as I had the answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTimer isn't necessarily meant for this sort of use...From the docs on NSTimer:

> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the
>   run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able
>   to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various
>   input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of
>   the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100
>   milliseconds. If a timer’s firing time occurs while the run loop is in
>   a mode that is not monitoring the timer or during a long callout, the
>   timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer.
>   Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be
>   a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time.

A better approach, if you are moving UIImages that are contained in a UIImageView would be to use the class animation methods on UIView. You can still get the same result of moving the image after a particular time if you use the animation method that contains a delay. The method is:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Using this method, you can specify the time of the animation (how long it takes to animate the move of your UIImages), how long to wait before starting this animation, a set on animation options, a block of animation code, and a block that executes when the animation is complete.

Comment: It's possible the OP is using Core Animation in the timer callback. That's why we need to see the code.

Comment: Certainly possible. It doesn't change the fact IMHO that UIView animations are better suited for, and actually intended for, this sort of action over an NSTimer. What's more, using blocks like with the UIView animations helps prevent the fragmented code you sometimes get by calling a method that fires a method somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that UIView animations (a wrapper around Core Animation) might be used in the callback, and that the OP might just be abusing a timer to get repetition instead of using CA's repeat/completion handler functionality.

Comment: Oh absolutely. Regardless, that timer's gotta go :)